# R what is the best way to get previous week number from date if the actual one is 1

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm looking for the best way to find a previous week number if the actual one is 1, like we have now. I'm always using `lubridate::isoweek(date)-1` (I need week starting from Sun) to get previous week number but now this doesn't work since I get 0 and I need 52 (or 53 depending on prev. years), how do you solve it? I can do a lag or other solutions but maybe it's more simpler approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove seven days from the date:

```r
library(lubridate)
date = as.Date("2023-01-03")
isoweek(date - days(7))
#[1] 52
```

Or 1 week:

```r
isoweek(date - weeks(1))
#[1] 52
```

Comment: omg, that was so simple :) thank you very much!

Comment: The example will work only one week in the new year ? :-)

Comment: Ahah, that's true, I edited ;)